# HBase get records in batches

Tags: apache, hbase

I am new to Apache HBase. I am trying to get millions of records from hbase in batches. Using "startrow" and "endrow" doesn't help because they look for the data in one region server only. We need to get all the data from all region servers in batches. We are trying to use "rowfilter" with binary comparator along with "setlimit" but with no luck. Can anyone help us to solve the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should set batch and cache size. [Here](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/perf.reading.html) is good article.